# how to control mysql query execution time between two table

Tags: php, mysql, database

```
SELECT a, b,c, table1.a, e FROM table1, table2    
WHERE (table1.a = table2.a and table2.id='111')   
and TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF( NOW( ) , table2.time )) < 172800
```

my query is of this type where in a and id are indexes in both table1 and table2.
This query is taking long time to execute.Both tables have million of data.How can I solve this?

Comment: What do you need for millions of records? And show us what you tried so far.

Comment: SELECT finishedon,language, round_over.round_id,password FROM players_over,round_over WHERE (players_over.email='1' and players_over.round_id = round_over.round_id) and TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF( NOW( ) , round_over.finishedon )) < 172800

Comment: apart from this code, what are you using for your connection string? if you are using `localhost` try using `127.0.0.1` which sped up my mysql queries alot.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that this bit:

```
TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF( NOW( ) , table2.time )) < 172800
```

renders it impossible to use any index on `table2.time` as the column is wrapped by a function.

You can try and rewrite it so that the plain column is on the left, and all the function-stuff on the right e.g.

```
table2.time > (NOW() - 172800)
```

assuming `time` is in seconds (which it probably isn't, since you are using TIME_TO_SEC, but you get the general idea).

Also....run this with EXPLAIN (just add the word EXPLAIN to the front of your query and run it) to see where the work is going.

Comment: table2.time >=DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 DAY)
I have used this but query is still slow

Comment: @Joy: can you quantify "still slow"? What does your query plan look like? Are you getting full table scans or index usage that is still  with significant overhead etc.etc.?

Comment: I added index on table2.time column which is a datetime type.Shall I remove index from this column?

Comment: I've got no idea if that is a good idea until you give us some information about the query plan.

Comment: How can I get query plan?Shall I explain query?

Comment: Like I said in my answer, just prepend the word "explain" i.e. `EXPLAIN SELECT a, b,c, table1.a, e FROM table1, table2    
WHERE (table1.a = table2.a and table2.id='111')   
and TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF( NOW( ) , table2.time )) < 172800;`